# NSManagedObject - setting custom instance variables across threads

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManagedObject class for which I have added a custom instance variable, by making it a property and using @synthesize (but not using 'transient' in the Core Data model). This works fine if I set the value and read it later within the same thread; but if I set the value for this property in a different thread, it still shows nil on the main thread.

As an example, think of a this:

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject{

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *personImage; // unmodeled
```

If I set the personImage object in the background thread, it's still 'nil' on the main thread.

Is there a way to fix this so that the property actually stores the value across threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to "fix" it because it is not broken.  Each context (and thus each thread) will have a separate instance of the `NSManagedObject`.  They are completely different objects in memory and will not share instance variables.  You will need to initialize that instance variable in each instance.

That is why `awakeFromInsert` and `awakeFromFetch` fire on each context.  It gives you an opportunity to initialize those instance variables.

Comment: Thanks. I guess then there is no way to merge data from the different threads directly, without some intermediary cache to read/write from

Comment: Correct.  If you are storing an image, you should have a cache that is outside of the `NSManagedObject` anyway that your UI can access and that you can control for release of memory, etc.